# Laravel Controller Class doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm having a really odd issue. Something I've never encounted in Laravel before.

`Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController does not exist`

Firstly, the file structure is fine. The controller is clearly there.

Secondly, my route `Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index');`
seems to be fine, it's not returning any route errors.

Thirdly, I checked the namespace of my Controller which is `namespace App\Http\Controller\Admin;` normal and the starting class line is `class AdminController extends Controller { }` which again is normal.

I then went on to check my function, it exists,

```
function index() {
  if (!Auth::user()->administrator) {
    return Redirect::to('https://http.cat/403');
  }
  return Redirect::to('https://http.cat/200');
}
```

It does!

The commands that I used to clear the cache:

`composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`

What have I done wrong to get this error?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use composer `dump-autoload` or anything else. You need just to set correct namespaces. This works:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
```

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. I don't how I didn't pick it up but I forgot an 's' in the namespace. How silly of me. Cheers for the help :)

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin thank you so much i totally forgot about adding the sub-folder to namespace path .. you saved me a lot of time of seaching

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin   I had the same problem, but this wasn't a solution for me!!! namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Aboutcontroller extends Controller
{
    //
    public function show() {
        return view('about');
    }
} still the same problem. What else would be?